# Error en script de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqldb

tengo un problema con un trabajo cron.

Resulta que tengo un script que funciona como uptobox, sin embargo el cron está configurado para que cada determinado tiempo haga unas tareas, borrar archivos y cosas así, pero cuando se ejecuta el cron tengo la siguiente salida. Ya revise y los datos de la base de datos con correctos, el script en sí mismo (el sitio web) funciona sin problemas, pero al ejecutarse el cron me dice que los datos no pudieron acceder. Solo existe un archivo de configuración con los datos de conexión a la base, y el sitio web se conecta y trabaja pero el cron no.

No entiendo mucho de PHP y de MySQL pero espero me puedan ayudar.

```
Failed connecting to the database with the supplied connection details. Please check the details are correct and your MySQL user has permissions to access this database.
Failed connecting to the database with the supplied connection details. Please check the details are correct and your MySQL user has permissions to access this database.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on bool in /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php(319): App\Core\Database->query()
#1 /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php(242): App\Core\Database->resulter()
#2 /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php(183): App\Core\Database->getRows()
#3 /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php(50): App\Core\Framework::initConfigIntoMemory()
#4 /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php(24): App\Core\Framework::init()
#5 /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/tasks/process_file_queue.cron.php(29): App\Core\Framework::runLight()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /home/mrva/web/misitio.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php on line 121
```

Les adjunto los archivos que interactuan y llevan a este error

Framework.class.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Core;
use App\Core\Database;
use App\Helpers\BannedIpHelper;
use App\Helpers\CoreHelper;
use App\Helpers\PluginHelper;
use App\Helpers\LogHelper;
use App\Helpers\RouteHelper;
use App\Helpers\SessionHelper;
class Framework
{
    const VERSION_NUMBER = '5.2.0';
    public static function run()
    {
        self::init();
        self::autoload();
        LogHelper::initErrorHandler();
        self::registerSession();
        self::postInit();
        self::dispatch();
    }
    public static function runLight()
    {
        self::init();
        self::autoload();
    }
    private static function init()
    {
        define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        define('DOC_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../'));
        define('APP_ROOT', DOC_ROOT . '/app');
        define('CORE_FRAMEWORK_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/core');
        define('CORE_FRAMEWORK_HELPERS_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/helpers');
        define('CORE_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARIES_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/libraries');
        define('CORE_APPLICATION_CONTROLLERS_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/controllers');
        define('CORE_APPLICATION_TEMPLATES_PATH', APP_ROOT . '/views');
        define('CORE_FRAMEWORK_SERVICES_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/services');
        define('LOCAL_SITE_CONFIG_BASE_LOG_PATH', DOC_ROOT . '/logs/');
        require DOC_ROOT . '/_config.inc.php';
        if (!ini_get('date.timezone'))
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
        }
        self::iniSets();
        define('WEB_ROOT', _CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL . '://' . _CONFIG_SITE_FULL_URL);
        define('CORE_WEB_ROOT', _CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL . '://' . _CONFIG_CORE_SITE_FULL_URL);
        include_once CORE_FRAMEWORK_ROOT . '/Database.class.php';
        include_once CORE_FRAMEWORK_ROOT . '/BaseController.class.php';
        include_once CORE_FRAMEWORK_ROOT . '/Auth.class.php';
        self::initConfigIntoMemory();
        define('PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_NAME', 'plugins');
        define('PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_ROOT', DOC_ROOT . '/' . PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_NAME . '/');
        define('PLUGIN_WEB_ROOT', WEB_ROOT . '/' . PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        define('CORE_APPLICATION_WEB_ROOT', WEB_ROOT . '');
        define('DOWNLOAD_TRACKER_UPDATE_FREQUENCY', 15);
        define('DOWNLOAD_TRACKER_PURGE_PERIOD', 7);
        define('ADMIN_FOLDER_NAME', 'admin');
        define('ADMIN_WEB_ROOT', WEB_ROOT . '/' . ADMIN_FOLDER_NAME);
        define('ACCOUNT_WEB_ROOT', WEB_ROOT . '/account');
        define('CACHE_DIRECTORY_NAME', 'cache');
        define('CACHE_DIRECTORY_ROOT', DOC_ROOT . '/' . CACHE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        define('CACHE_WEB_ROOT', WEB_ROOT . '/' . CACHE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        define('SITE_THEME_DIRECTORY_NAME', 'themes');
        define('SITE_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT', DOC_ROOT . '/' . SITE_THEME_DIRECTORY_NAME . '/');
        define('SITE_THEME_WEB_ROOT', WEB_ROOT . '/' . SITE_THEME_DIRECTORY_NAME . '/');
        define('CORE_ASSETS_WEB_ROOT', CORE_APPLICATION_WEB_ROOT . '/app/assets');
        define('CORE_ASSETS_ADMIN_WEB_ROOT', CORE_ASSETS_WEB_ROOT . '/admin');
        define('CORE_ASSETS_ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/assets/admin');
    }
    private static function postInit()
    {
        CoreHelper::checkMaintenanceMode(_INT_PAGE_URL);
        $db = Database::getDatabase();
        $currentLanguage = isset($_SESSION['_t']) ? $_SESSION['_t'] : SITE_CONFIG_SITE_LANGUAGE;
        $languageImagePath = '';
        $languageDirection = 'LTR';
        $languageDetails = $db->getRow("SELECT id, flag, direction " . "FROM language " . "WHERE isActive = 1 " . "AND languageName = :languageName " . "LIMIT 1", array(
            'languageName' => $currentLanguage,
        ));
        if ($languageDetails)
        {
            $languageDirection = $languageDetails['direction'];
            if (SITE_CONFIG_LANGUAGE_SEPARATE_LANGUAGE_IMAGES == 'yes')
            {
                $languageImagePath = $languageDetails['flag'] . '/';
            }
            define('SITE_CURRENT_LANGUAGE_ID', (int)$languageDetails['id']);
            $_SESSION['_tFlag'] = $languageDetails['flag'];
        }
        define('SITE_LANGUAGE_DIRECTION', $languageDirection);
        $siteTheme = SITE_CONFIG_SITE_THEME;
        if ((isset($_SESSION['_current_theme'])) && (strlen($_SESSION['_current_theme'])))
        {
            $siteTheme = $_SESSION['_current_theme'];
        }
        define('SITE_CURRENT_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT', SITE_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT . $siteTheme);
        define('SITE_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ROOT', SITE_CURRENT_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT . '/assets/' . $languageImagePath . 'images');
        define('SITE_CSS_DIRECTORY_ROOT', SITE_CURRENT_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT . '/assets/' . $languageImagePath . 'styles');
        define('SITE_JS_DIRECTORY_ROOT', SITE_CURRENT_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT . '/assets/' . $languageImagePath . 'js');
        define('SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH', SITE_CURRENT_THEME_DIRECTORY_ROOT . '/views');
        define('SITE_THEME_PATH', SITE_THEME_WEB_ROOT . $siteTheme);
        define('SITE_IMAGE_PATH', SITE_THEME_PATH . '/assets/' . $languageImagePath . 'images');
        define('SITE_CSS_PATH', SITE_THEME_PATH . '/assets/' . $languageImagePath . 'styles');
        define('SITE_JS_PATH', SITE_THEME_PATH . '/assets/' . $languageImagePath . 'js');
        $bannedIP = BannedIpHelper::getBannedType();
        if (strtolower($bannedIP) === "whole site")
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
            die();
        }
        CoreHelper::setupOldPaymentConstants();
        if (_CONFIG_DEMO_MODE == true)
        {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['_p']))
            {
                $_SESSION['_plugins'] = false;
                if ((int)$_REQUEST['_p'] == 1)
                {
                    $_SESSION['_plugins'] = true;
                }
                PluginHelper::loadPluginConfigurationFiles(true);
            }

            if (!isset($_SESSION['_plugins']))
            {
                $_SESSION['_plugins'] = false;
                PluginHelper::loadPluginConfigurationFiles(true);
            }
        }
        PluginHelper::loadPluginConfigurationFiles();
        PluginHelper::callHook('postFrameworkInit');
    }
    private static function iniSets()
    {
        @ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    }
    private static function registerSession()
    {
        if (SITE_CONFIG_USER_SESSION_TYPE === 'Database Sessions')
        {
            SessionHelper::register();
        }
        session_name('filehosting');
        session_set_cookie_params((int)SITE_CONFIG_SESSION_EXPIRY);
        session_start();
    }
    private static function autoload()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array(
            __CLASS__,
            'load'
        ));
        require_once (APP_ROOT . '/libraries/vendor/autoload.php');
    }
    private static function load($className)
    {
        if (!strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
        {
            $className = basename($className);
        }
        $className = str_replace('\\', DS, $className);
        $filename = basename($className) . '.class.php';
        $className = strtolower(dirname($className)) . DS . $filename;
        if (file_exists(DOC_ROOT . DS . $className))
        {
            require_once (DOC_ROOT . DS . $className);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Error: Could not auto load class: ' . $className . '<br/><br/>Ensure you\'ve set a "use" statement at the top of your code.<br/><br/>';
            $e = new \Exception();
            $error .= nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
    private static function dispatch()
    {
        RouteHelper::processRoutes();
    }
    private static function initConfigIntoMemory()
    {
        $db = Database::getDatabase();
        $rows = $db->getRows('SELECT config_key, config_value ' . 'FROM site_config ' . 'ORDER BY config_group, config_key');
        if (COUNT($rows))
        {
            foreach ($rows AS $row)
            {
                $constantName = 'SITE_CONFIG_' . strtoupper($row['config_key']);
                if (!defined($constantName))
                {
                    define($constantName, $row['config_value']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Database.class.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use \PDO;

class Database
{
    // singleton object. Leave $me alone.
    private static $me;
    public static $queries = array();
    public $db = false;
    public $host;
    public $name;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $dieOnError;
    public $result = null;
    public $redirect = false;
    private $reconnectCount = 0;

    // Singleton constructor
    private function __construct($connect = false) {
        $this->host = _CONFIG_DB_HOST;
        $this->name = _CONFIG_DB_NAME;
        $this->username = _CONFIG_DB_USER;
        $this->password = _CONFIG_DB_PASS;
        $this->dieOnError = _CONFIG_DEBUG;
        if ($connect === true) {
            $this->connect();
        }
    }

    // Get Singleton object
    public static function getDatabase($connect = true, $forceReconnect = false) {
        if (is_null(self::$me) || $forceReconnect === true) {
            self::$me = new Database($connect);
        }

        return self::$me;
    }

    // Do we have a valid database connection?
    public function isConnected() {
        return is_object($this->db);
    }

    // Do we have a valid database connection and have we selected a database?
    public function databaseSelected() {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }

        $result = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES");

        return is_object($result);
    }

    public function connect() {
        // check if we already have a connection
        if ($this->db !== false && $this->isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }

        // check for the MySQL PDO driver
        if ($this->havePDODriver() == false) {
            $this->notify('PDO driver unavailable. Please contact your host to request '
                    . 'the MySQL PDO driver to be enabled within PHP.');
        }

        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->name . ";charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password);

            // catch errors if debug is enabled
            if (_CONFIG_DEBUG === true) {
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->notify('Failed connecting to the database with the supplied connection '
                    . 'details. Please check the details are correct and your MySQL user '
                    . 'has permissions to access this database.');
        }

        if ($this->isConnected()) {
            // disable strict mode in MySQL
            $this->db->exec("SET sql_mode = ''");

            // set utf8
            $this->db->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
        }

        return $this->isConnected();
    }

    public function reconnect() {
        $this->db = false;
        $this->reconnectCount++;

        return $this->connect();
    }

    public function close() {
        $this->result = null;
        self::closeDB();
    }

    public static function closeDB() {
        if (!is_null(self::$me)) {
            self::$me->db = null;
            self::$me = null;
        }
    }

    public function query($sQL, $args = null) {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            $this->connect();
        }

        // allow for prepared arguments. Example:
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sQL);
        $debugSql = $sQL;
        $params = array();
        if (is_array($args)) {
            foreach ($args AS $name => $val) {
                $params[':' . $name] = $val;

                $replacement = "'" . $val . "'";
                if (is_int($val)) {
                    $replacement = $val;
                }
                elseif ($val === null) {
                    $replacement = 'null';
                }

                $debugSql = preg_replace('/:\b' . $name . '\b/u', $replacement, $debugSql);
            }
        }

        $start = microtime();
        $startEx = explode(' ', $start);
        $start = $startEx[1] + $startEx[0];

        // track query
        $nextIndex = $this->numQueries();
        self::$queries[$nextIndex] = array(
            'sql' => $debugSql,
            'start' => $start,
        );
        try {
            $sth->execute($params);
        }
        catch (\PDOException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() != 'HY000' || !stristr($e->getMessage(), 'server has gone away') || $this->reconnectCount >= 3) {
                $this->notify($e);
            }

            // if we have "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL
            // server has gone away", try to reconnect and re-run query
            $this->reconnect();

            return $this->query($sQL, $args);
        }
        $end = microtime();
        $endEx = explode(' ', $end);
        $end = $endEx[1] + $endEx[0];

        $total = number_format($end - $start, 6);
        self::$queries[$nextIndex]['end'] = $end;
        self::$queries[$nextIndex]['total'] = $total;

        $this->result = $sth;

        return $this->result;
    }

    // Returns the number of rows.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function numRows($arg = null) {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);

        return ($result !== false) ? $result->rowCount() : false;
    }

    // Returns true / false if the result has one or more rows
    public function hasRows($arg = null) {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg);

        return is_object($result) && ($result->rowCount() > 0);
    }

    // Returns the number of rows affected by the previous operation
    public function affectedRows() {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->result->rowCount();
    }

    // Returns the auto increment ID generated by the previous insert statement
    public function insertId() {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }

        $id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        if ($id === 0 || $id === false) {
            return false;
        }

        return $id;
    }

    // Returns a single value.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getValue($arg = null, $args_to_prepare = array()) {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg, $args_to_prepare);
        $data = false;
        if ($result) {
            $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            if (is_array($row) && array_key_exists(0, $row)) {
                $data = $row[0];
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    // Returns the first row.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getRow($arg = null, $args_to_prepare = array(), $fetchType = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg, $args_to_prepare);
        $data = $result->fetch($fetchType);

        return $result->rowCount() ? $data : false;
    }

    // Returns an array of all the rows.
    // You can pass in nothing, a string, or a db result
    public function getRows($arg = null, $args_to_prepare = array(), $fetchType = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
        $result = $this->resulter($arg, $args_to_prepare);
        $data = $result->fetchAll($fetchType);

        return $result->rowCount() ? $data : array();
    }

    // Escapes a value and wraps it in single quotes.
    public function quote($var) {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            $this->connect();
        }

        return $this->db->quote($var);
    }

    // Escapes a value.
    public function escape($var) {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            $this->connect();
        }

        $str = $this->db->quote($var);
        if (strlen($str) > 2) {
            $str = substr($str, 1, strlen($str) - 2);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    public function numQueries() {
        return count(self::$queries);
    }

    public function lastQuery() {
        if ($this->numQueries() > 0) {
            return self::$queries[$this->numQueries() - 1];
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function notify($errMsg = null) {
        if ($errMsg === null) {
            $errors = $this->db->errorInfo();
            $errMsg = implode(".", $errors);
        }
        error_log($errMsg);

        if ($this->dieOnError === true) {
            echo "<p style='border:5px solid red;background-color:#fff;padding:12px;font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'><strong>Database Error:</strong><br/>$errMsg</p>";
            $lastQuery = $this->lastQuery();
            if ($lastQuery !== false) {
                echo "<p style='border:5px solid red;background-color:#fff;padding:12px;font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'><strong>Last Rendered Query:</strong><br/>" . $lastQuery['sql'] . "</p>";
            }

            echo "<pre>";
            debug_print_backtrace();
            echo "</pre>";
            exit;
        }

        if (is_string($this->redirect)) {
            header("Location: {$this->redirect}");
            exit;
        }
    }

    // Takes nothing, a MySQL result, or a query string and returns
    // the correspsonding MySQL result resource or false if none available.
    private function resulter($arg = null, $args_to_prepare = array()) {
        if (is_null($arg) && is_object($this->result)) {
            return $this->result;
        }
        elseif (is_object($arg)) {
            return $arg;
        }
        elseif (is_string($arg)) {
            $this->query($arg, $args_to_prepare);
            if (is_object($this->result)) {
                return $this->result;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function havePDODriver() {
        // check for pdo driver
        if (!class_exists('PDO')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * To fetch Only the next row from the result data in form of [key][value] array.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array|bool   false on if no data returned
     */
    public function fetchAssociative() {
        return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Counts the number of rows in a specific table
     *
     * @access public
     * @param   string  $table
     * @return  integer
     *
     */
    public function countAll($table) {
        return (int) $this->getValue('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count '
                        . 'FROM ' . $table);
    }

}
```

process_file_queue.cron.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Tasks;

// include framework
use App\Core\Framework;
use App\Helpers\BackgroundTaskHelper;
use App\Helpers\FileActionHelper;
use App\Helpers\FileHelper;
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../core/Framework.class.php'));

// setup light environment
Framework::runLight();

// background task logging
BackgroundTaskHelper::start();          
                            
// process delete queue
FileActionHelper::processQueue('delete');

// process move queue
FileActionHelper::processQueue('move', 1);

// process restoration queue
FileActionHelper::processQueue('restore', 50);

// update storage stats
FileHelper::updateFileServerStorageStats();

// background task logging
BackgroundTaskHelper::end();
```

Salida cambiando notify

```
object(PDOException)#3 (8) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "could not find driver"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(70) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(72)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(70) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(72)
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "__construct"
      ["class"]=>
      string(3) "PDO"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(70) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(30)
      ["function"]=>
      string(7) "connect"
      ["class"]=>
      string(17) "App\Core\Database"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(70) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(37)
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "__construct"
      ["class"]=>
      string(17) "App\Core\Database"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(71) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(182)
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "getDatabase"
      ["class"]=>
      string(17) "App\Core\Database"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(71) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(50)
      ["function"]=>
      string(20) "initConfigIntoMemory"
      ["class"]=>
      string(18) "App\Core\Framework"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(71) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(24)
      ["function"]=>
      string(4) "init"
      ["class"]=>
      string(18) "App\Core\Framework"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(5) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(80) "/home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/tasks/process_file_queue.cron.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(29)
      ["function"]=>
      string(8) "runLight"
      ["class"]=>
      string(18) "App\Core\Framework"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errorInfo"]=>
  NULL
}
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on bool in /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php(80): App\Core\Database->notify()
#1 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php(30): App\Core\Database->connect()
#2 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php(37): App\Core\Database->__construct()
#3 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php(182): App\Core\Database::getDatabase()
#4 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php(50): App\Core\Framework::initConfigIntoMemory()
#5 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Framework.class.php(24): App\Core\Framework::init()
#6 /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/tasks/process_file_queue.cron.php(29): App\Core\Framework::runLight()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /home/mrva/web/uptomycloud.xyz/public_html/app/core/Database.class.php on line 286
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128286/discussion-on-question-by-armando-vazquez-error-en-script-de-mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error personalizado que tienes aquí (lo cual es una buena práctica):

```
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->notify('Failed connecting to the database with the supplied connection '
                . 'details. Please check the details are correct and your MySQL user '
                . 'has permissions to access this database.');
    }
```

Estaba ofuscando el problema real en fase de depuración. De hecho, cuando vi el mensaje de error que indicabas en la pregunta pensé que había un problema con las credenciales de conexión, sin reparar en que era un mensaje personalizado.

En fase de depuración, cuando hay errores, conviene mostrar los errores reales, para encontrar la causa verdadera del problema (el objeto `Exception en este caso se encuentra en` $e`  y debe ser depurado).

Al cambiar **temporalmente** el fragmento anterior por esto:

```
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->notify( var_dump($e) );
    }
```

Rápidamente afloró el problema real:

```
object(PDOException)#3 (8) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "could not find driver"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
```

El error *`could not find driver`* indica que o no tienes instalado o no tienes activado el controlador PDO en tu servidor, por tanto no podrás usar PDO mientras no tengas instalado/activado dicho controlador. Es por eso por lo que la conexión no se realizaba nunca.

Revisa tu archivo `php.ini` para verificar si no es simplemente una desactivación. Si no hay nada sobre PDO considera instalarlo siguiendo las instrucciones dadas para tu sistema operativo / versión de PHP.

Una vez resuelto el problema, recuerda poner en `notify()`  el mensaje personalizado, pues no es recomendable mostrar trazas de error en producción. Dichas trazas contienen información muy valiosa para los hackers.

Por otra parte, tu método de verificación del controlador no estaría funcionando:

```
private function havePDODriver() {
    // check for pdo driver
    if (!class_exists('PDO')) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Intenta ponerlo así:

```
private function havePDODriver() {
    #Esto retornará true o false si PDO está cargado o no
    return extension_loaded ('PDO');
}
```